# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n 2x_{i-1}x_i < 1+ \sum_{i=1}^n 2x_{i-1}^2$ if $x_0=0, x_n = 1$ and $x_{i-1} < x_i \forall i$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n 2x_{i-1}x_i < 1+ \sum_{i=1}^n 2x_{i-1}^2$ if $x_0=0, x_n = 1$ and $x_{i-1} < x_i \ \forall i \in \lbrace1,2,3,\dots n\rbrace$.

I've been struggling with this one for a while.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you tried so far?

Comment: Can this be any useful? $(x_i - x_{i-1})^2 = x_i^2 + x_{i-1}^2 - 2x_ix_{i-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that $(x_i-x_{i-1})^2>0$, so:
$$0 < \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1})^2$$

Now, try to expand the term in the parentheses and rearrange the inequality to get yours. Note also that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = x_n + \sum_{i=2}^n x_{i-1}^2$$